# asp.net mvc project using firebird database error in foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, firebird

I am using Firebird as the database I need to develop a b2b application using ASP.NET MVC 5. Is there an error in the use of foreign keys between tables and can you add the necessary fixes? The error that Visual Studio gives is as follows:  An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but not handled in user code.

I did not get any errors while working on a single non-related table. I think I am mistaken about establishing relationships between tables.

DatabaseContext class , this class database connection ;

```
namespace InoturYolcuKayit.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(FirebirdContextConfiguration))]
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext()
            : base(new FbConnection(@"database=D:\data\INOTUR.FDB;charset=WIN1254;user=sysdba;password=ino38sis;"), true)
        { }

        public DbSet<PERSONEL> Personel { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ROLES> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FirebirdContextConfiguration Class :

```
namespace InoturYolcuKayit.Models
{
    class FirebirdContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public FirebirdContextConfiguration()
        {
            SetDatabaseInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

PERSONEL.cs Firebird database in table;

```
public class PERSONEL
{
  [Key, Required]
  public int PERSONEL_NO { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(30)]
  public string ADI { get; set; }

  public int ULKE_NO { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ROLES")]
  [Column("ROLE_ID")]
  public int ROLE_ID { get; set; }

  public ROLES ROLES { get; set; }                 

}
```

ROLES.cs firebird database in table;

```
public class ROLES
{
    public ROLES()
    {
       PERSONEL = new List<PERSONEL>();
    }

    [Key, Required]
    public int ROLE_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string ROLE_NAME { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<PERSONEL> PERSONEL { get; set; }

}
```

I am getting this error on `ROLES_ID` in a simple line of code that lists the index viewda staff in the `PERSONELS` controller:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but not handled in user code.

```
public class PERSONELsController : Controller
{
    private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    // GET: PERSONELs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var personel = db.Personel.Include(p => p.ROLES);
       return View(personel.ToList());
    }
}
```

This error stacktrace ;

```
    [InvalidOperationException: Sequence does not contain matching items]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +2643765
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name) +81
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +87
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.BinaryPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +120
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration) +138
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action) +130
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration) +94
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride) +154
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride) +585
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +177
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +423
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +376
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +444
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +55
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +616
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +54
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +375
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   hacumre.Controllers.HEDIYELERsController.Index() in C:\Users\Abdullah\source\repos\hacumre\hacumre\Controllers\HEDIYELERsController.cs:21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9987157
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: ooo sory , i am not writing. Firebird database.

Comment: Then edit your question and fix it

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: hi @MarkRotteveel stacktrace in buttom

Comment: @Abdullah have you test my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In your PERSONNEL class, you inverted DataAnnotations between properties, and the `Roles` property is not virtual, please use :

```
  [Column("ROLE_ID")] // facultative cause the property has the same name
  public int ROLE_ID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("ROLE_ID ")]
  public virtual ROLES ROLES { get; set; }
```